# What's the easiest way to use a switch statement when I don't know how many things need to be compared against?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

So I have a terminal into which the user types commands.

I take the first phrase of the command and run it through a switch statement to work out what to do.

```
switch(phrases[0]) {
    case "boot":
        // Do something
        break;
    case "switch":
    case "app":
    case "change":
    case "switchapp":
    case "changeapp":
        // Do something
        break;
    case "help":
        // Do something
        break;
    case "wipe":
    case "erase":
    case "restart":
    case "forget":
    case "clear":
    case "undo":
        // Do something else here
        break;
    default:
        throw new Error("Unknown command: " + phrases[0]);
}
```

Note that for each command I've got a few alternatives to make it more likely for the user to pick a correct command on their first try.

However - if I have all of those alternatives in an array instead of hard-coded into the switch function, how do I access them?

I've considered using if/else combined with .some() but that seems clunky:

```
if(bootCommands.some(function(name){return name == phrases[0]}))
    // Do something
if(switchCommands.some(function(name){return name == phrases[0]})) {
    // Do something
} else if(helpCommands.some(function(name){return name == phrases[0]})) {
    // Do something
} else if(wipeCommands.some(function(name){return name == phrases[0]})) {
    // Do something
} else {
    throw new Error("Unknown command: " + phrases[0]);
}
```

There's an easier way, surely?

Comment: `wipeCommands.includes(phrases[0])` instead of `some` in current sceanrio

Comment: I would use a Set here, .->  `const wipeCommands = new Set(["wipe", "clear", "erase"]); if (wipeCommands.has("wipe")) console.log("wiped"); `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still use `switch-case` expression with [`Array.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

```
switch(true) {
    case bootCommands.includes(phrases[0]):
        // Do something
        break;
    case wipeCommands.includes(phrases[0]):
        // Do something
        break;
    default:
        throw new Error("Unknown command: " + phrases[0]);
}
```

```js
var bootCommands = ["boot"],
  wipeCommands = ["wipe", "erase", "restart", "forget", "clear", "undo"],
  command = "restart";



switch (true) {
  case bootCommands.includes(command):
    // Do something
    console.log("Boot command: " + command);
    break;
  case wipeCommands.includes(command):
    // Do something
    console.log("Wipe command: " + command);
    break;
  default:
    console.log("Unknown command: " + command);
}
```